# Cannot publish Facebook Open Graph Post in Swift

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-opengraph

```
FBRequestConnection.startForPostOpenGraphObject(graphObject, {connection, result, error in 
    if(!error) {
        var objectID : NSString = result.objectforKey("id")
        println(objectID)
    } else {
        println(error.description)
    }
})
```

I'm getting the following error on the expression:

**Cannot convert the expression's type 'FBRequestConnection!' to 'Void'**

I have looked all over SO but couldn't find a solution. Any ideas?

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check your handler syntax. It should be something like:

```
    let handler:FBRequestHandler = { (connection : FBRequestConnection!, result : AnyObject!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(error)
        } else {            
            println(result)
        }
    }
```

Myself, I'm struggling with getting **FBOpenGraphObject** from **FBGraphObject.openGraphObjectForPost()**